# Same query runs on one table, on the other it doesn't MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have finally made a query which solves part of my problem.

This one works.

```
UPDATE tng_people AS savenije
JOIN tng_people AS Temporary ON savenije.personID = Temporary.personID 
SET savenije.birthplace = Temporary.birthplace
WHERE  savenije.birthplace = "" and Temporary.birthplace = "Winschoten, Groningen, Nederland"
```

However when I run the query slightly altered on another, much smaller table, it times out

```
UPDATE tng_families AS savenije
LEFT JOIN tng_families AS Temporary ON savenije.marrplace 
SET savenije.marrplace = Temporary.marrplace
WHERE  savenije.marrplace = "" and
Temporary.marrplace = "Winschoten, Groningen, Nederland" and savenije.familyID = Temporary.familyID
```

I get the following error message

#1969 - Query execution was interrupted (max_statement_time exceeded)

Which I don't understand, since the table is much smaller, with way less overhead

tng_families 88.3 MiB   619,053 rows The query would affect 3,389 records

tng_people 554.8 MiB    1,639,103 the query affected 8,873 records,

The helpdesk suggested to split up the query which wasn't very helpful, I could try to search through less records but the result is the same. It's a shared server so I don't have access to the settings

WHAT AM I MISSING??

Let me clarify, I have two sets of data one, a month old, one the most recent, somehow in the most recent one, the place name "Winschoten, Groningen, Nederland" disappeared and I don't know when but less than a month ago. By replacing the places where personID and familyID are identical, the placename is back

Comment: `LEFT JOIN tng_families AS Temporary ON savenije.marrplace` here is the problem. it should be `LEFT JOIN tng_families AS Temporary ON savenije.marrplace =Temporary.something`

Comment: *when I run the query slightly altered* NO. This is **absolutely** another query. 1) First query updates **some** rows in `tng_people` whereas second one updates **all rows** in `tng_families`. 2) First query is deterministic if `personID` is unique whereas second one is **not** deterministic (by the reason described in @ErgestBasha's comment).

Comment: Ergest Basha, your query gives me an error message, familyID is just as unique as personID

Comment: Let me clarify, I have two sets of data one, a month old, one the most recent, somehow in the most recent one, the place name "Winschoten, Groningen, Nederland" disappeared and I don't know when but less than a month ago. By replacing the places where personID and familyID are identical, the placename is back.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section